# floating point raises divide by zero error in GNU smalltalk (gst)

Tags: macos, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I installed gnu small talk in my Mac using port.

```
sudo port install gst
```

The version is 3.2.5

```
gst -v
GNU Smalltalk version 3.2.5
Copyright 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Written by Steve Byrne (sbb@gnu.org) and Paolo Bonzini (bonzini@gnu.org)
```

It seems to be working fine, but when I tested floating point number, I got divide by zero error message.

```
st> 123.323
Object: 1 error: The program attempted to divide a number by zero
ZeroDivide(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
SmallInteger(Number)>>zeroDivide (SysExcept.st:1426)
Fraction>>setNumerator:setDenominator: (Fraction.st:485)
Fraction class>>numerator:denominator: (Fraction.st:66)
Fraction>>- (Fraction.st:151)
FloatD(Float)>>printOn:special: (Float.st:533)
FloatD(Float)>>printOn: (Float.st:436)
FloatD(Object)>>printString (Object.st:534)
FloatD(Object)>>printNl (Object.st:571)
st>
```

I could bypass this issue by attaching "e0".

```
st> 123.323e0
123.323
```

However, I still get an error with some numeric operations involving floating point numbers.

```
st> 1.1 sin
Object: 1 error: The program attempted to divide a number by zero
ZeroDivide(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
```

Sometimes it works fine.

```
st> 3.14 sin
0.0016
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I need to attach e0 to all the floating point numbers.

```
st> 1.1e0 sin
0.8912074
```

Or even with just e only

```
st> 1.1e sin
0.8912074
```

Comment: What happens if you try with suffix d instead of e?

Comment: @aka.nice: 1d1 or 1d3 -> OK, 1d0 -> crash 1d -> crash

Comment: I asked because e exponent will create a single precision floating point (FloatE) while d will creates a double precision (FloatD). Presumably FloatD is the default if you don't provide an exponent (There is a FloatD on your stack dump). So it sounds like a buggish behavior of printOn:special: that shows up with double precision...

Answer (score 2):

According to [a thread in a Smalltalk forum](http://forum.world.st/Bug-float-is-printed-wrongly-tp5082826p5082828.html), this problem is caused by gst compiled with the `-pie` option, which is the default in many Linux distros, and maybe in Mac port too.

To solve this problem, compile gst with `-no-pie` option: Download gst 3.2.5 from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/smalltalk/, extract the tarball, and then compile & install

```
export CFLAGS='-no-pie'
export LDFLAGS='-no-pie'
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This solution works fine on my Linux Mint PC.

Comment: Wonderful! This saved me probably two hours of fruitless debugging.